# Finding Green's function for the following problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, greens-function

Let me first write what is asked:

Given the operator $L = \dfrac{d}{dx^2} + k^2$ over the space of twice-differentiable functions:

1. Prove that $L$ is linear.
2. Find the Green function for $L$, under boundary conditions $G(0,y) = G\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2k},y\right)=0$.
3. Solve the boundary problem
   \begin{align}
   \begin{cases}
   &Lf(x) = p(x)=x\\
   &f(0) = f\left( \dfrac{\pi}{2k} \right) = 0
   \end{cases}
   \end{align}
   and prove that the solution can be written as
   \begin{align}
   f(x) = \int_{0}^{\dfrac{\pi}{2k}}G(x,y)p(y)dy.
   \end{align}

My attempted solution is this (the first subquestion is trivial), starting from (2)
\begin{align}
LG(x,y) = \delta(x-y) = \begin{cases} 0, \ x \neq y\\ \infty, \ x = y \end{cases}.
\end{align}

- For $x \in [0,y)$ we have
  \begin{align}
  &G(x,y) = A(y) \cos (kx) + B(y) \sin (kx)\\
  &G_{-}(0,y) = 0 \implies G_{-}(0,y) = A(y) \implies G(x,y) = B(y) \sin (kx), \ x \in [0,y).
  \end{align}
- For $x \in (y, \dfrac{\pi}{2k} ]$ we have
  \begin{align}
  &G_{+}(x,y) = C(y) \cos(kx) + D(y) \sin(kx)\\
  &G_{+}\left( \dfrac{\pi}{2k}, y \right) =0 \implies G_{+} \left( \dfrac{\pi}{2k}, y \right) = D(y)
  \end{align}
  so
  \begin{align}
  G_{+}(x,y) = C(y) \cos(kx), \ x \in (y, \dfrac{\pi}{2k}].
  \end{align}
- For $x=y$ we have continuity, so:
  \begin{align}
  B(y) \sin(ky) = C(y) \cos(ky)
  \end{align}
  and by integrating over $\left[ y-\epsilon, y+\epsilon \right]$:
  \begin{align}
  kB(y)\cos(ky) + kC(y) \sin(ky) = -1
  \end{align}
  gives us
  \begin{align}
  \begin{cases}
  B(y) &= -\dfrac{\cos(ky)}{k}\\
  C(y) &= -\dfrac{\sin(ky)}{k}
  \end{cases}
  \end{align}
  and therefore
  \begin{align}
  G(x,y) = 
  \begin{cases}
  -\dfrac{1}{k} \cos(ky) \sin(kx), \ x \in [0,y)\\
  -\dfrac{1}{k} \sin(ky) \cos(kx), \ x \in (y, \dfrac{\pi}{2k}].
  \end{cases}
  \end{align}

For (3), my work was
\begin{align}
L f(x) = x &\implies \left( \dfrac{d^2}{dx^2} + k^2 \right)f(x) = x\\
&\implies \dfrac{d^2}{dx^2}(f(x)) + k^2 f(x) = x\\
&\implies f''(x) + k^2 f(x) = x.
\end{align}
To solve this is pretty much trivial. The homogeneous equation is $f_{hom} = c_1 \cos(kx) + c_2 \sin (kx) $ and by using any known method for arriving at the full solution (I did a simple polynomial substitution) we get that $f_{par} = \dfrac{1}{k^2}x$.

At any rate we get
\begin{align}
f(x) = c_1 \cos(kx) + c_2 \sin(kx) + \dfrac{1}{k^2}x
\end{align}
and by applying the boundary conditions we get
\begin{align}
&f(0) = 0 \implies c_1 = 0\\
&f\left( \dfrac{\pi}{2k} \right) = 0 \implies c_2 = - \dfrac{\pi}{2k^3}.
\end{align}
I am stuck at how am I supposed to prove that the Green function found above can be connected to the solution of my problem for
\begin{align}
f(x) = \int_{0}^{\dfrac{\pi}{2k}}G(x,y)p(y)dy.
\end{align}

Comment: You reduce the degree of the polynomial factor via partial integration, until only the trigonometric functions remain in the integrand. Or employ some trick like $x=\frac{d}{da}\sin(ax)|_{a=0}$ to immediately reduce to trigonometric identities.

Comment: @LutzLehmann i am on the right way? what do you mean by reducing the degree?

Comment: Yes, the solution per undetermined coefficients looks good. My remarks were for evaluating the integral with the Green kernel.